# Does Exception Java API violates Liskov Principle?

Tags: java, oop, exception, solid-principles

According to the java.lang.Exception hierarchy:
    [image]

And given the Liskov Substitution Principle: *... if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S...*

We have two different behaviors for sub-classes (Checked vs Unchecked) and there are scenarios where we can not effectively replace the base class usage with a subclass object unless we change the current code, for example, if we write code like:

```
try{
     InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C://test.txt");//throws IOException                        
     while((i=is.read())!=-1){
        c=(char)i;            
        System.out.print(c);
     }
  }catch(Exception e){// can not be replaced by any subtype, but IOException
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Is this a violation?, why/why not?.

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html

### EDIT 1

Example 2:

Given the method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void test() throws Exception{
        // nice stuff
    }
}
```

And the client:

```
public class MyTest {

    MyClass clazz = new MyClass();

    // 'Exception' can not be changed by a subclass directly
    public void testTest() throws Exception { 
        clazz.test();
    }
}
```

### EDIT 2

You are telling me that I can create a subclass and override the method and no throw an exception, that is completely valid, but is not what I want to show you.

When I say 'Exception' can not be changed by a subclass directly, I was meaning: you can not write something like:

```
// You can not do this at home
public class MyTest {

    MyClass clazz = new MyClass();

    // hey look!, there is a compiler error!
    public void testTest() throws NullPointerException { 
        clazz.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably, but does it matter?  The whole point of having checked and unchecked exceptions is to give programmers a choice.  I'd personally rather get flogged than have to use checked exceptions everywhere, but some programmers love them.  *They're all `Throwable`.*

Comment: What do you mean by: "can not be replaced by any subtype" ? it *can* be changed with `catch(IOException e)`

Comment: @alfasin if you catch other subtype (ie: NPE), the code must be changed, (or you throw the IOE or you create other catch block)

Comment: @Chechus true, but that's a different *subtype* of `Exception`. I guess that what I don't understand (from the question) is, how is it violating Liskov Substitution Principle ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey certainly is just plain and morbid curiosity :), there are arguments that maybe  I am missing. I am not sure if that is a real violation.

Comment: It's not violating Liskov principle, and as for your "can't be raplaced..." yes it can. Your argument is invalid, not because you are forced to write another catch block, or throw the IOE, that doesn't mean you can't replace the catch block with any other subclass of Exception.

Comment: @J.Lucky please read the EDIT, are you still sure that is not a violation?

Comment: @Chechus, yes it can be changed. If you have a subclass of MyTest, you can have something like: `public void testtest() throws NullPointerException`

Comment: @J.Lucky in that case the subclass cant replace the base class (the one who throws Exception), AFAIK "*If looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, but need batteries, you are doing it wrong*", that is why I think that is a violation: We need to change the code if we replace the base class with a subclass, i.e: we are putting the batteries.

Comment: @Chechus, *"the subclass cant replace the base class"* Why not? I can have something like `MyTest mt = new MySubclassTest();`

Comment: @J.Lucky please read the edit2, there is a confusion when I said "subclass", now the example 2 is more accurate

Comment: @Chechus, you're getting error because your method is throwing a broader than NullPointerException. It has nothing to do with LSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LSP means you can use any subclass *instance* wherever a base class *instance* is expected. Not that you can arbitrarily change class *names* in your code, as in your 'catch' example. Otherwise, OO programs would be unwritable.

Your second example is merely incorrect. The 'throws Exception' *can* be replaced by any subclass of Exception. Not that it's an example of the LSP either way.

Comment: please read the edit2, there is a confusion when I said "subclass", now the example 2 is more accurate

Comment: Your edit 2 still has nothing to do with the LSP whatsoever. You still aren't getting the point. The LSP doesn't say you can arbitrarily change *class names* anywhere in your program text. It says what I said in my first sentence of my answer. You can use subclass *instances* wherever base class *instances* are expected.

Comment: @Chechus, *maybe* you're misunderstanding the LSP.

Comment: Not anymore with the explanation of EJP, thank you for your simplicity!.